# WScript.Shell vs cmd.exe - WorkingDir differences?

Tags: command-line, cmd, activex, wsh, working-directory

I've got an ActiveX script which starts an application.

```
var shell =  new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run('appli.exe');
```

The script works fine. Nevertheless, if I open cmd.exe and type in `appli.exe` I get an error, that it is an unknown command.

Appli.exe is placed in C:\Programs... and shell.CurrentDirectory gives `C:\Users\ABC\Desktop`. So the WorkingDir can't be the answer, why it works in WScript.Shell and why it doesn't in CMD.

So how does WScript.Shell find the path for Appli.exe and why isn't cmd.exe able to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to start a process in windows. The `Run` method of the `WScript.Shell` object uses `ShellExecute` (or a variation of it as `ShellExecuteEx`). This windows API function uses a different criteria than by ex. `CreateProcess` (used by a direct call to the application from command line) to locate applications.

One of the differences between the two API functions is where they look to find the applications.

[`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) searchs in current active directory, parent process current active directory, windows system directory and directories included in path.

[`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) [also checks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the contents of the registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications
```

You can replicate the same behaviour using the `start` command from command line to start your application.

```
start appli.exe
```

Comment: Yes. Unlike `ShellExecuteEx` function (both `.run('appli.exe')` and `start "" appli.exe`  from command prompt), [`CreateProcess` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) (`appli.exe` from command prompt) does not search the per-application path specified by the `App Paths` registry key.

Comment: @JosefZ, This is what I was trying to expose. It seems I was not clear enough. Changed.